# how to make perl to execute 3rd party commands

Tags: perl

I got a problem while doing task in perl. Through that script, first I want to go the other path and then execute the command situated in that path.

eg: `<drive>\Program Files\<software>\bin` and the command here is say, `xyz -c`

So, how to do it ? What I have done is -->

```
my $command = '<drive>\Program Files\<software>\bin';

$sts = `("$command\\xyz -c")`;
print $sts;
```

but this won't work saying

```
Not an internal or external command.
```

And when I manually goes to this particular drive in cmd, and execute the command, it works..

Regards,
Vik

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$sts = `("$command\\xyz -c")`;
```

with

```
$sts = `"$command\\xyz -c"`;
```

and try again.

To make sure that you are using a valid file path, you could replace the above code with

```
if (-f "$command\\xyz") {
    $sts = `"$command\\xyz -c"`;
    print $sts;
}
```

Comment: @gaussblurinc Actually, I am worried about that `<driver>`.

Comment: @gaussblurinc Looks like the asker is using Windows, those backslashes should not be a problem.

Comment: No, its not working by replacing the above character. I guess it is not going in the path. What to do that it first enters the path and then execute ? Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: @user3560745, I think that wind is your problem :) but, without jokes, I think that your problem in file existence. Please, read about **File::Spec**, **File::Basename** modules. They will help you

Comment: @user3560745 Make sure that you are trying to run a file that does exist. Please check out my update answer.